# PDO lastInsertId() returns 0 when using on duplicate key update?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got a query like the following:

```
$a = $members->prepare("insert into a(name) values(:name) 
                            on duplicate key update name = :name");
```

Then when I do:

`$insert_id = $a->lastInsertId()`

If the query successfully inserted a row, it will return the insert id as expected, if it updated a row, it will also return the updated row id as expected (sort of). But if it neither inserted or updated anything because everything was the same, then it just returns 0.

I guess this is pretty logical default behaviour, but is there a way to change it so that it can return the id of the row it attempted to update, like it does when it actually changes something in the row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are many places to find the answer on this, but the specificity to PDO may be hindering your search results...

First, make sure to add `id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` to the `ON DUPLICATE` clause, as noted at the bottom of [the DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). The `id` in this case is the column name of your primary key (so in your case it may/may not be titled `id`).

Also, you may have to specify a sequence object argument to `->lastInsertId()` to make it work. I've encountered that problem in certain circumstances before.

Comment: Luckily / unfortunately (depends on how you look at it), MySQL has only the `AUTO_INCREMENT` sequence, so unless it has some non-standard extensions, for `MySQL` `->lastInsertId()` without arguments is fine, contrary to `PostreSQL` and the like.

Answer (score 1):

No, because there is no row it 'attempts' to update. Also, be careful: if you had another insert query before that in the same session, you could get value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` from that previous query.

Comment: that's why it's not LAST_INSERT_ID() but LAST_INSERT_ID(id)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to supplement the accepted answer. Using `LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` does the trick, setting the value returned by `PDO::lastInsertId()` to that of the updated row.

```
$dbh->query("create table users (
    user_id int primary key auto_increment, 
    user_name varchar(255), 
    user_email varchar(255) unique)"
);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (
        `user_name`, 
        `user_email` 
    ) VALUES (
        ?, 
        ? 
    ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       `user_id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`user_id`), 
       `user_name` = VALUES(user_name),
       `user_email` = VALUES(user_email);
';
//note user_id is the primary column of the users table 
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
// inserting the new record with id=1
$statement = $sth->execute( array('test', 'test@gmail.com') );
echo $dbh->lastInsertId();
// inserting the new record with id=2
$statement = $sth->execute( array('test', 'test1@gmail.com') );
echo $dbh->lastInsertId();
// updating the record with id=1 that does a change
$statement = $sth->execute( array('test2', 'test@gmail.com') );
echo $dbh->lastInsertId();
// updating the record with id=1 that doesn't do any changes
$statement = $sth->execute( array('test2', 'test@gmail.com') );
echo $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

Which returns `1211` as expected.

Comment: Hello. Although this question has been answered already, but thank you for taking time to write the code. I fixed some errors in it and also made it relevant to the question asked.

Comment: Hello, thanks for editing the code, so the $name parameter isn't needed to get the last insert id?

Comment: As well as transactions and cursor. In mysql, there can be only one AI field, and its value always returned by lastInsertId, no matter what you pass as parameter.

Comment: Ah now I see. You misattributed the outcome to the lastInsertId's parameter, while it was actually a LAST_INSERT_ID's parameter that you already used in your code.